# Riddle Poem: I'm always on a plane, won't fit on a boat or train

Tags: riddle

Who or what is this poem referring to?

```
I'm always on a plane
Won't fit on a boat or train

Unlike most of my brethren
I travel with no companions

Simultaneously cold and hot
I can be a dark or light spot

To some I may be unrecognizable
At times I'm not even visible

From my routine I never deviate
But sometimes I'm seen doing the opposite

I've suffered battering and bruising
Since I've no protective layering

Subjected to a stiff breeze
No one near me can breathe
```

Comment: That's why it's not a jet engine. :)

Comment: Arg, the contradictions in this poem!

Comment: @IanMacDonald You have good intentions, but the poem seems a little too personal to edit, given how much time I put into it.  Hope you understand.

Comment: @pacoverflow No problem. Carry on!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is it

> Mercury (the planet)?

I'm always on a plane
Won't fit on a boat or train

> Each planet has an orbital plane

Unlike most of my brethren
I travel with no companions

> Has no moon

Simultaneously cold and hot
I can be a dark or light spot

> Cold and dark on the far side, hot on the sun side. Dark if in front of the Sun and light if not

To some I may be unrecognizable
At times I'm not even visible

> Often mistake for a star. Not always visible.

From my routine I never deviate
But sometimes I'm seen doing the opposite

> Always orbiting the Sun, but planets appear in retrograde sometimes

I've suffered battering and bruising
Since I've no protective layering

> No atmosphere. Gets hit by stuff

Subjected to a stiff breeze
No one near me can breathe

> Mercury's magnetic field is weak enough to not protect from solar wind. No atmosphere to breathe

Comment: Yes but see if you can get the "plane", "dark or light spot", and "breeze" clues.

Comment: @pacoverflow I took another shot at those clues.

Comment: There is a more elegant answer for the "plane" clue.

Comment: Its orbital plane doesn't change.

Comment: For the "plane" reference, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic

Comment: It's not correct to say "the planets orbit on a plane", since each planet has its own orbital plane.  But yeah, orbital plane is what I'm looking for.